# Cholesky Decomposition in R package "vars"

Tags: econometrics, r

I'd like to know if, when running a VAR model in R (package "vars"), the cholesky decomposition matrix is upper triangular (so I should order my variables from more endogenous to less endogenous), or lower triangular (so I should order my variables from less endogenous to more endogenous).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to page 6 of [the documentation for *vars*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vars/vars.pdf), the Cholesky decomposition matrix is lower triangular:

> The long-run impact matrix is the lower-triangular Choleski decomposition of the above matrix and the contemporaneous impact
>   matrix is equal to:
>
> $$(I_K − A_1 − \dots − A_p)Q$$
>
> where $Q$ assigns the lower-triangular Cholesky decomposition.

In the theoretical literature, Cholesky factorization is traditionally defined as lower-triangular; that is, as $A = L L^{T}$. There is a function is base R, *chol()*, that returns the upper-triangular Cholesky decomposition of a matrix $X = R^{T}R$.